# Non-nullable warning with EF core DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

If I have a DbContext as follows (which is a standard db context):

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IAudit
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    
    public DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; set; }
}

public interface IAudit
{
    DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; set; }
}
```

I have nullable reference types turned on.

I get a warning on the constructor:

Non-nullable property 'Audit' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.

How can I get make this warning go away (and keep the interface)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just fixed it like this. Need to make the property read only.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IAudit
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
    
    public DbSet<Audit> Audit => Set<Audit>()
}

public interface IAudit
{
    DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; }
}
```

Comment: It's not that you made the property read-only, but rather that you gave it a non-null value before object construction was complete.

Comment: Pointed me in the right direction. Found these official docs after seeing your post. Thank you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types

Comment: Correcting @EricJ.'s correction, it's not that you gave it a non-null value before object construction was complete, but that you gave it instructions to how to generate a value every time it is accessed, so there isn't an "initial value" intrinsically. Initializing a readonly property would look like this: `public DbSet<Audit> Audit {get;} = Set<Audit>();` (but in this case that wouldn't work as the assignment expression runs in the static context and `Set` is an instance method)

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, starting with C#11 (.NET 7) one can also use the `required` modifier to mark that a property needs to be set by an object initializer. Since we don't manually instance the DbContext, we can therefore use it in this case:

```cs
public required DbSet<Audit> Audit { get; set; }
```